# Is this a good method to make ImageView square?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview, android-view

Parent layout has a specified **width** value (50dp), and **height** set to `MATCH_PARENT`. In that layout I am adding a few `ImageView` widgets using Java, and because parent layout has specified **width**, I can set **width** and **height** of each `ImageView` to `MATCH_PARENT` and using Java I can make that `ImageView` square by setting its **height** as **width**.

This is my code:

```
public class Icon extends ImageView {

    public AppIcon(final Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public AppIcon(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AppIcon(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int width, final int height)
    {
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    }

}
```

Is this a good method to make each `ImageView` square? I think it's too simple, like something is missing.

P.S.: My method works, but I need to be sure, that everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working one but it can be enhanced. See my code:
Updated my code.

The image will be scaled based on the measured width and height and whichever is smaller.

```
public class Icon extends ImageView {

public Icon(final Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public Icon(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public Icon(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
        final int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
    super.onMeasure(width, height);
    int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int measuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
    if (measuredWidth > measuredHeight) {
        setMeasuredDimension(measuredHeight, measuredHeight);
    } else {
        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredWidth);

    }

}

}
```